# Segmentation Fault in speller.c - CS50

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, cs50, singly-linked-list

I am currently working on the pset5 of CS50, however I am stuck on the first function that needs to be done: load().
The load function should load all the string from a file "dictionary" and should return true if all the file has been loaded, and return false when the program should run into an issue while loading them (e.g. running out of space).
I completed the function however when I try to run (after compiling) it gives me a segmentation fault, but I cannot understand where it comes from.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    
    #include "dictionary.h"
    
    typedef struct node {
        char word[LENGTH + 1];
        struct node *next; } node;
    
    const unsigned int N = 26;
    
    node *table[N];
    
    // Hashes word to a number
    unsigned int hash(const char *word)
    {
        int i = toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
        return i;
    }
    
    // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
    {
        // Allocate temporary memory
        char *tmp = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file\n");
            return false;
        }
    
        // Open file
        FILE *d = fopen(dictionary, "r");
        if (d == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file\n");
            return false;
        }
    
        // Until EOF: create new node, point new node to table[key] -> next, point table[key] to new node.
        while (fscanf(d, "%s", tmp) != EOF)
        {
            node new;
            int key = hash(tmp);
    
            strcpy(new.word, tmp);
            new.next = table[key] -> next;
            table[key] -> next = &new;
        }
    
        free (tmp);
        return true;
    }
```

For more information you can refer here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/5/speller/

Can you help me understand where the seg fault issue is?

Answer (score 0):

In  this while loop

```
    while (fscanf(d, "%s", tmp) != EOF)
    {
        node new;
        int key = hash(tmp);

        strcpy(new.word, tmp);
        new.next = table[key] -> next;
        table[key] -> next = &new;
    }
```

the local variable new is created anew in each iteration of the loop. The previously used variable new is not alive in each iteration of the loop.

And in any case the variable new will not be alive after executing the while loop.

You need to allocate an object of the type node dynamically as for example

```
node *new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );
```

Another problem is that the array `table` contains initially null pointers. So this expression

```
table[key] -> next
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you should write (new is a pointer as I already showed)

```
new->next = table[key];
```

That is a new node is inserted in the beginning of the list.

Comment: thank you! that sorted everything! 
However, I have a question. Now that I wrote  "new -> next = table[key]" I set table[key] as the last element of the list right? So if then I need to search something inside the list how do I exactly do?

Comment: @Freddy Each new node is inserted in the beginning of the list  starting from the pointer table[key]. So if you will insert "A", "AA" in this order then the list will look like "AA" -> "A" -> NULL.

Comment: But following the method above, new is the origin of the list and table[key] is the end. I don't have access to new location as it is a temporary address, I only have access to table[key]. however the next location stored inside of table[key] is null. So basically I have: new { var = foo, next = table[key] }; table[key] { var = NULL, next = NULL }; If I try to access table[key] I won't be able to access new, right?

Comment: @Freddy Initially table key is equal to NULL. Then a new node is added if becomes the new node in the list due to these statements    new->next = table[key];
        table[key] = new;

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code, first, when you call malloc function, I think it should be `char *tmp = malloc((LENGTH + 1)*sizeof(char));` the second thing I want to tell you is that you make an fopen, but you don't make an fclose at the end of your program.

I don't know if this is going to solve your problem, but if it continues check if you are accessing to a position of the array table that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The SEGFAULT comes from implementing the second comment of your source code.
Read-up on "linked lists" and how they work.

```
bool load( const char *dictionary ) {
    // Open the dictionary file and check
    FILE *fp = fopen( dictionary, "r" );
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf( "Could not open '%s'\n", dictionary );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    char buf[ sizeof(table[0].word) ]; // Same size!!

    // Loop, reading and storing words
    while( fscanf( fp, "%s", buf ) != EOF ) {

        int key = hash( buf ); // calculate a hash
        if( key < 0 || N <= key ) {
            printf( "'%s' hash (%d) out of range [0-%d]\n", buf, key, N-1 );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        // Allocate a new node
        node pn = malloc( sizeof( *pn ) );
        if( pn == NULL ) {
            printf( "Out of memory\n" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
        // Store word into this node
        strcpy( pn->word, buf );
       pn->next = NULL; // fully initialise malloc'd space

        // PREpend this node (reverse sort order) to appropriate linked list
        pn->next = table[ key ];
        table[ key ] = pn;
    }

    // Close the dictionary file
    fclose( fp );
    return true;
}
```

It is always a good idea to test return values from functions that one knows "will never fail". Notice that even the return from `hash()` is checked.

The words stored in this list will be in reverse sort order. You will have to account for that when searching the list for a particular word.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! 
I tried to change everything you told me, however the segmentation fault stays unless I remove the line:

table[ key ]->next = pn;

which I think was the same issue present in my original code.

Comment: @Freddy Oops! I've corrected that mistake in my example... Have another look, please...

Comment: @Fe203 Yesterday I at the end sorted it out, but the problem was indeed that I was setting table[key]-> next to something while table[key] was null in the first place. 
I eventually figured it out on my own but thank you for your reply :3